# Check a list of lists for a specific value in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have

```
list_of_lists = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'] , ['b','c'] , ['c'] ]
```

and I want to determine whether or not

```
'd'
```

is a member of my list of lists. How do I go about doing that in Python?

Comment: `'d' in itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)`

Comment: I would just use a for loop: `any('d' in sub for sub in list_of_lists)`

Comment: Why are there ***answers*** in the comment boxes above? Surely a better place to put them would be in the ***answer*** boxes below :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precise answer to your question (whether 'd' is a member of my list of lists) is

```
'd' in list_of_lists
```

But I suspect your question is just poorly worded

If your question was whether 'd' is a member of one of the items of list_of_lists, then the answer is

```
any('d' in lst for lst in list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can define a function, so it can handle **arbitrary** nested list.

```
def flatten(container):
    for item in container:
        if isinstance(item, list):
           for inner_item in flatten(item):
               yield inner_item
        else:
           yield item

>>> 'd' in flatten([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b','c'], ['c']])
False
>>> 'd' in flatten([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b','c', ['d']], ['c']])
True
```